# Could not generate script from SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I would like to generate script of SQL Azure database after connecting to sql server R2 but it gives me error when i will do that.

> ### > TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Script failed for Server 'myserver'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1540+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Script+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server 'myserver'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1540+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attempt+to+retrieve+data+for+object+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I am generating script as usual as we do with sql server database.

Is there any special ways to generate scripts?  My goal is to take backup of SQL Azure database to Sql server database. Please any one can help me to sort out this issue?

Thanks 
Arun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Redgate SQL Azure backup tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/) and it did backup perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Installing the [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727) for SQL Server 2008 R2 helped for me.

There is a similar [problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2459027) with Denali CTP1, which suggests that this is fixed in [Cumulative Update 5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438347).