# SQL Azure: SMO Exception when scripting objects in SSMS 2008 R2

Tags: exception, ssms, azure-sql-database, smo

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to manage a SQL Azure database.  When I try to right-click on any of the objects in the database, and do Script Table As -> CREATE -> New Query Editor Window, I get the following exception screen every time:

[image: SQL Azure SMO Exception When Scripting Objects]

Scripting for SELECT -> New Query Editor Window is the only option that seems to work without generating an Exception like above.  Any ideas??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not generate script from SQL Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357507/could-not-generate-script-from-sql-azure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are additional details about this issue.

Latest service update for SSMS:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2507770

Blog discussing the necessary upgrade: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/ssdsgetstarted/thread/3dd65548-cf58-41e8-804d-3f6873132a7b