# SSMS 2008 R2 cannot generate script from Windows Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, ssms

When I try to do this:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Why is this happening and is there any alternative way to get the script to create this table?

Thanks for your help.

It seems my issue is similar to this [Could not generate script from SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357507/could-not-generate-script-from-sql-azure) but I would like a better solution if available.

**Edit: I get this error when trying to install SP1:**

[image]

**Edit:  This is my system information:**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it is SSMS 2012 and not SSMS 2008 or 2008 R2 trying to run against a WASD database? What does Help | About say? Have you applied Service Pack 1?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ahh.  Good point.  It appears I am using 2008 R2.  I thought I installed 2012...  So you say to install 2012 or apply service pack 1 to 2008 R2?

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using 2008 R2 tools to connect to WASD, which is kind of 2008 R2 + 2012 hybrid. You should always try to make sure that your client tools are >= the highest instance you're managing.

So to fix this I would say you should stop using the 2008 R2 tools and instead install [Management Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) and then perhaps add [Cumulative Update #5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2861107). Note that fully featured Management Studio no longer requires licensing.

On the SP1 page, for a 64-bit OS, you want:

> SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

On the CU5 page, you want:

> SQLServer2012_SP1_CU5_2861107_11_0_3373_x64

Comment: When I go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579 and click Download, it asks me which file I want.  I am not sure.  I am on a 64bit OS (Windows 7).  Also, when I go to download the cumulative update http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2861107&kbln=en-us it asks which ones I want also.  The file names are quite ambiguous.  Which one should I choose?

Comment: Thanks, Aaron.  But, I am getting an error when trying to install SP1.  I have edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: @user1477388 Ok, what operating system are you using? Please help me help you by providing all of the relevant information. You see that the error message is because of your operating system, so since I don't know what operating system you're using, my only suggestions are going to be: (1) upgrade to a newer operating system if you are on, say, XP; (2) apply the relevant operating system service pack it states is required if you are on, say, Vista; or (3) live with the error and find a different way to generate scripts (e.g. 3rd party tools).

Comment: I am on Windows 7 64bit.  Please see my screenshot of my system info I just added to the question.  Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @user1477388 you're going to have to install Service Pack 1 for Windows 7. Do this through Windows Update (and install all of the other updates too).